# Rails - set_table_name in model depending on domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 site that operates on various different domains and would like to use _set_table_name within one of my models to change the table name dynamically based on the domain being requested. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_table_name` is deprecated in favor of `table_name=`. Use it:

```
SomeModel.table_name = request.subdomain=='foo' ? 'foos' : 'bars'
```

Comment: Is this thread safe? It seems like if two subdomains hit two threads at the same time, the model will be sharing the table_name between the two.

Comment: That's what I'd like to know as well. Anyone got an answer? My guess would be it is thread-safe, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I don't see any way this could be thread safe. This method is intended to be used once per class (at class load time), not dynamically per request.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is untested code, but it’s a concept that I think is more “with the grain” of Rails, and it should be thread-safe for deployments where that matters.

```
class SomeModel
  def self.subdomain_class(subdomain)
    @subdomain_classes ||= {}
    unless @subdomain_classes[subdomain]
      @subdomain_classes[subdomain] ||= Class.new(self)
      @subdomain_classes[subdomain].table_name = "#{self.table_name}_#{subdomain}" # This needs sanitizing, of course
    end

    @subdomain_classes[subdomain]
  end
end

class SomeModelsController
  ...

  private
  def CurrentSomeModel
    SomeModel.subdomain_class(request.subdomain)
  end
end
```